# Change of coordinate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_2$ be defined by $T(a,b) = (a+2b, 3a-b)$. Let $B = [(1,1),(1,0)]$ and $C = [(4,7),(4,8)]$. Find $[T]_B$ and $[T]_C$ and show that $[T]_C = Q^{-1} [T]_B Q$ for some invertible matrix $Q$.

How do you calculate matrix $Q$? Is it gonna be the matrix that changes basis from $B$ to $C$ or from $C$ to $B$? Whenever I calculate it then do the matrix multiplication to see if I get $[T]_C$ it doesn't work out.

For $[T]_B$ I get {2 3 1 -2} and $[T]_C$ {31 36 -53/2 -31}. Are those at least correct? What should $Q$ be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various methods of finding the matrix of $T$ with respect to a basis $B$.  One of them is to work out one column at a time: if the basis is $\{{\bf b}_1,{\bf b}_2\}$ then you find the first column by calculating $T({\bf b}_1)$ and finding its coordinate vector with respect to $B$, and similarly for the other column(s).  Here you have
$$\eqalign{T(1,1)&=(3,2)=2(1,1)+(1,0)\cr T(1,0)&=(1,3)=3(1,1)-2(1,0)\ ,\cr}$$
so the matrix is
$$M=\pmatrix{2&3\cr1&-2\cr}\ .$$
For $C$ we have
$$\eqalign{T(4,7)&=(18,5)=31(4,7)-(53/2)(4,8)\cr T(4,8)&=(20,4)=36(4,7)-31(4,8)\cr}$$
and the matrix is
$$N=\pmatrix{31&36\cr -53/2&-31\cr}\ .$$
We have
$$N=Q^{-1}MQ$$
where the columns of $Q$ are the coordinate vectors of vectors in $C$, relative to the basis $B$.  Since
$$(4,7)=7(1,1)-3(1,0)\quad\hbox{and}\quad (4,8)=8(1,1)-4(1,0)$$
we have
$$Q=\pmatrix{7&8\cr-3&-4\cr}\ .$$
You can, and should, **check** that $QN=MQ$.

The best way IMO to understand the relation between $M$ and $N$ is to write
$$T({\bf x})=I^{-1}(T(I({\bf x})))$$
where $I$ is the identity map on ${\Bbb R}^2$.  On the left hand side we use the basis $C$ to find a matrix for $T$; on the right hand side we will use the basis $B$ for $T$, and for $I$ the basis $C$ in the domain and $B$ in the codomain.  This gives $I$ the matrix $Q$ as specified above.

Comment: Thank you. Im just not sure if I understand if and why Q should be from C to B or from C to B?

Comment: See updated answer, hope it helps.

Comment: How can you apply T, which is in basis B, on I which takes something from basis C to basis B? Shouldn't T be in basis C for it  to work so I could take it from C to B?

Comment: Sorry but I think you have some fundamental misconceptions here, and you probably need to ask your instructor face to face because it's very hard to discuss these things online.  But I'll give it a try anyway.  The function $T$ is not actually "in basis $B$" or "in basis $C$" at all, $T$ is just $T$.  The $T$ represented by $M$ is *the same* as the $T$ represented by $N$.  It is $M$ which is applied to *coordinate vectors* wrt $B$, giving a result which is also a coordinate vector wrt $B$; and $N$ likewise for $C$. . . to be continued

Comment: And $Q$ takes the coordinates wrt $C$ of a vector ${\bf x}\in{\Bbb R}^2$, and produces the coordinate vector wrt $B$ of the same vector ${\bf x}$.  Multiplying by $M$ now gives the coordinate vector of $T({\bf x})$ wrt $B$, as stated above.